# Find index of column by using name

Tags: excel, vba

```
Option Explicit

Function FindIndexCol(rngIndexRow, rngIndexCol) As String

    Set rngIndexRow = Worksheets("sheet1").Range(rngIndexRow)
    Set rngIndexCol = rngIndexRow.Find(rngIndexCol)

    FindIndexCol = Split(Cells(1, rngIndexCol.Column).Address, "$")(1)
End Function


Sub Test()
    Dim Purchasing_Document, Backup_Purchasing_Document  As String

    Purchasing_Document = FindIndexCol("1:1", "Purchasing Document")
    Backup_Purchasing_Document = FindIndexCol("1:1", "Backup Purchasing Document")
End Sub
```

I am using `FindIndexCol()` function to get the index of the column by name. `Purchasing_Document` should return me the column A and `Backup_Purchasing_Document`  will return me column K. But both of them are returning me character K. How should I change the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if you declare `Dim Purchasing_Document, Backup_Purchasing_Document As String` only the last variable is a `String` but the first is a `Variant`. In VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable: `Dim Purchasing_Document As String, Backup_Purchasing_Document As String`.

The documentation of the [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) states:

> *The settings for* `LookIn`, `LookAt`, `SearchOrder`, *and* `MatchByte` *are saved each time you use this method. If you do not specify values for these arguments the next time you call the method, the saved values are used.*

So if using `Find` you should at least specify these 4 parameters or you cannot predict which setting `Find` is using for these parameters.

Also `LookAt:=xlWhole` is necessary to distinguish between `"Purchasing Document"` and `"Backup Purchasing Document"` because the first is part of the second.

So at least do the following:

```vb
Public Function FindIndexCol(ByVal IndexRow As String, ByVal IndexCol As String) As String
    Dim rngIndexCol As Range
    Set rngIndexRow = Worksheets("sheet1").Range(IndexRow)

    Dim rngIndexCol As Range
    Set rngIndexCol = rngIndexRow.Find(What:=IndexCol, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchByte:=False)
    
    If Not rngIndexCol Is Nothing Then
        FindIndexCol = Split(Cells(1, rngIndexCol.Column).Address, "$")(1)
    Else
        'output some error if nothing was found
        MsgBox "Could not find '" & IndexCol & "' in '" & IndexRow & "'.", vbCritical
        'or return some error at least
        'FindIndexCol = "Column not found"
    End If
End Function


Public Sub Test()
    Dim Purchasing_Document As String, Backup_Purchasing_Document As String

    Purchasing_Document = FindIndexCol("1:1", "Purchasing Document")
    Backup_Purchasing_Document = FindIndexCol("1:1", "Backup Purchasing Document")
End Sub
```

---

Note that `FindIndexCol` only works in `sheet1` because of this line

```
Set rngIndexRow = Worksheets("sheet1").Range(rngIndexRow)
```

Therefore I suggest to make it more useful by making it more generic

```vb
Public Function FindIndexCol(ByVal rngIndexRow As Range, ByVal ColumnName As String) As String
    Dim rngIndexCol As Range
    Set rngIndexCol = rngIndexRow.Find(What:=ColumnName, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchByte:=False)
    
    If Not rngIndexCol Is Nothing Then
        FindIndexCol = Split(rngIndexRow.Parent.Cells(1, rngIndexCol.Column).Address, "$")(1)
    Else
        'output some error if nothing was found
        MsgBox "Could not find '" & ColumnName & "' in '" & rngIndexRow.Address(External:=True) & "'.", vbCritical
        'or return some error at least
        'FindIndexCol = "Column not found"
    End If
End Function


Public Sub Test()
    Dim Purchasing_Document As String, Backup_Purchasing_Document As String
    
    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        Purchasing_Document = FindIndexCol(.Rows(1), "Purchasing Document")
        Backup_Purchasing_Document = FindIndexCol(.Rows(1), "Backup Purchasing Document")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks PEH, the public function is really good idea for me to use this function among all sheet.

Comment: @Gunhanwei I realized I messed something up with the variable type declarations. Please check my edited anwser where I fixed that!

Comment: @PEH  I just tried the second method and it pop up some error ```object doesn't support property or method``` and highlight the line ```Purchasing_Document = FindIndexCol(.Row(1), "Purchasing Document")```

Comment: @Gunhanwei sorry my bad `.Row(1)` must be `.Rows(1)`. I fixed the typo.